# Provide "trigger-method" to module-(sub)-view model in WPF and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, module

I'm got an other question for my WPF/MVVM application I'm working on since a while.
The main idea is to use a main window providing a navigation bar and a `ContentControl`.

The different "Modules" are all built as `UserControl` with each its own ViewModel.

The main call from the main viewmodel to start a module is

```
private void ShowAddressModule() {
  ContentControlBindingProperty = new AddressModule(new AddressModuleViewModel);
}
```

In the real application the viewmodels are pre-loaded and so on, but the start is more or less the same.

The main view model contains a boolean property `LongRunningOperation` to do multiple operations on the main window while any long running operation.
As example showing a loading image or disable the main navigation while loading a new module or whatever.

So my idea is to provide a possibility to the modules (their view models) to active this "mode".
Example how it could look in the modules view model:

```
private void LoadContactList() {
  MainWindow.LongRunningOperation = true;
  LoadAllContactsInAThread(); /*Takes a long time*/
  MainWindow.LongRunningOperation = false;
}
```

I tried to mark the property as static and public, but this will not work because of the `OnPropertyChanged` event.

If possible it would be great if the solution could be applied also to methods (including parameters) from the main window - so (as example) the modules could use as example the parents statusbar or so.

```
MainWindow.ShowErrorMessageInStatusBar("The error xyz occured!");
```

Hopefully I described good enought, what's my idea...
And hopefully anybody could provide me the needed tip how to handle this requirement.

Thanks in advance for any hints

Regards Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each module could raise an event to indicate the start of a long running operation, and raise an event to indicate the end of a long running operation. Your main view model, when loading modules for the first time, could hook-up to these events and react to them accordingly.

Your sub view model would have some events like this:

**Sub view model**

```cs
public delegate void OnLongRunningOperationStartedEventHandler(object sender);
public delegate void OnLongRunningOperationFinishedEventHandler(object sender);

public event OnLongRunningOperationStartedEventHandler OnLongRunningOperationStarted;
public event OnLongRunningOperationFinishedEventHandler OnLongRunningOperationFinished;

private void LoadContactList() {
  OnLongRunningOperationStarted?.Invoke(this);
  LoadAllContactsInAThread(); /*Takes a long time*/
  OnLongRunningOperationFinished.Invoke(this);
}
```

And your main view model will hook-up to them like this:

**Main View Model**

```cs
public bool LongRunningOperation { get; private set; }

// Keep track of the number of modules currently running long operations
private int _countLongRunningOperations = 0;

public LoadSubModules(){
    // Depending on how you load your sub modules, this piece of code could move around
    foreach (var module in submodules){
        module.OnLongRunningOperationStarted += Module_LongOperationStarted;
        module.OnLongRunningOperationFinished += Module_LongOperationFinished;
    }
}

private void Module_LongOperationStarted(object sender){
    _countLongRunningOperations += 1;
    LongRunningOperation = true;
}

private void Module_LongOperationFinished(object sender){
    _countLongRunningOperations -= 1;
    if (_countLongRunningOperations == 0) {
        LongRunningOperation = false;
    }
```

The same principle (using events) could be used to bubble up error messages from each submodule to the main view model.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - works perfekt for me.
I implemented the method to create the async task and everything in my abstract module base method - within the actual method I only need to use a single line `StartLongRunningOperation(LoadContacts);`
So the code will look pretty clean

Answer (score 0):

**The quick and very dirty approach:**

Grab a reference to mainwindow out of application.current.mainwindow. Cast it to MainWindow. It's a property set to whatever the first window you show is - MainWindow just happens to be the default name of the main window.

You can then set the property on that if it's a public dependency property. Make sure the dp binds twoway in it's metadata.

This is bad because you're referencing ui in your viewmodels and you have no application when you run tests on viewmodels in some test runner.

**The quick and dirty approach**

Add a public property to app and set this to your instance of mainwindowviewmodel in it's ctor. You can reference app from an piece of code. Add a public property to mainwindowviewmodel and bind to that.

This is bad because you have no application when you run tests on viewmodels in some test runner.
You could add a static with an interface abstracts this away and work round that though.

**My suggestion**

This hinges on the fact you can use dot notation to bind and that includes 
 Content.IsBusy on yourcontentcontrol.

You can therefore bind from a parent window to a dependency property of any usercontrol that happens to be in it's contentcontrol.

Add that property using an attached property and bind that to IsBusy in a base viewmodel. Inherit the viewmodels of your child views from that.

One thing to mention is that binding to an attached property is a little odd and rather than just

```
 ElementName=YourContentControl, Path=Content.YourAttachedProperty
```

You need something like:

```
ElementName=YourContentControl, Path=Content.(local:AttachClass.YourAttachedProperty)
```